# How does pytorch autograd work when sampling is involved

Tags: pytorch

I have a simple NN whose output is connected to a Categorical distribution. This distribution is sampled multiple times during training. The loss function uses these samples to calculate the loss. In this case, does the autograd still work? I am trying to understand what kind of computational graph would be created for the loss function in this case as sampling is involved.

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine an SGD step:

[image: SGD step]

Here, $\theta$ represents the parameters of the neural network, $\eta$ is the step size. The $\omega$ represents an example in the dataset and D is the distribution of those examples. Notice that L(.,.) is the loss function.

The fact that we are interested in the expected value of the gradients is the source of the term "stochastic" and, as we don't know the distribution D, we have no other choice other than make a sample estimation of that gradient in practice.

TL;DR

The Automatic Reverse Mode Differentiation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation) happens for every example we propagate in our neural network. Hence, getting the gradients for a particular example is not stochastic. When a mini-batch is completed, i.e. we have several sample values for the gradient, we make a sample estimation of its expected value by taking the mean. Only then, the parameters are updated using SGD.